# Internet Explorer doesn't send cookie from an AJAX request

Tags: ajax, http, cookies

I have an HTML page which is making an AJAX request and getting a response with a cookie. The problem is that when I go to another page on the same domain, Firefox sends the cookie, but IE (9) does not. Is it related to its security configuration? I tried to play a bit with the cookie permissions, but to no avail.

Comment: What server side scripting language are you using to set the cookie ? PHP ? If so can you post your code that you're using to set the cookie ? You might not be setting it on the root of the site, maybe just the current page.

Comment: I'm using Java EE, and the path is indeed not the root of the site, but even when I'm sending requests with a matching path, the browser doesn't include the cookie. And anyway, it's got to be an IE issue, not a general cookie issue, because it works on Firefox.